# Not writing into an Excel file

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm reading the data from one file named `SPD_file`. Matching the data with another file named `Custom`. And all the records which are matching in both the files will be written into the third file.

But it seems that something is wrong, because the code is matching the records and printing on console. But when I'm writing into another file nothing is coming into the new file, other than the header.

```
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(SPD_file)
 worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
 mapping_records = {}
 for worksheet_name in worksheets:
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
    mapping_record = MappingRecord()
 if worksheet_name == "CD":
    for curr_row in range(0,worksheet.nrows):
        mapping_record = worksheet.row(curr_row)
        print worksheet_name
        print mapping_record[0].value
        for curr_row in mapping_record:
            #print "In Loop...."
            spd_record = MappingRecord()
            spd_record.id = "00002269"
            spd_record.erocode = None
            spd_record.scno = None
            mapping_records[mapping_record[8]] = spd_record
print "Read SPD File....."

custom_file_name = "Custom_" + today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".csv"
custom_file =  ops_home + path + "\\" + custom_file_name
custom = open(custom_file, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(custom, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for line in reader:
    if mapping_records.has_key(mapping_record[8]): 
        spd_record = mapping_records[mapping_record[8]]
        if line[7] == "ERO Code":
            spd_record.erocode = line[8]
        elif line[7] == "Service Number":
            spd_record.scno = line[8]


#create a new file.
New_file = ops_home + '\\Reports\\SPD_new_' + today.strftime('%d%m%Y') +   '.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(New_file)                                                            
# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
money = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
worksheetCd = workbook.add_worksheet("CD")
cdHeader = ("Merchant ID", "EroCode", "Service Number")
cd_row = 0
cd_col = 0
for columnHeader in cdHeader:
    worksheetCd.write(cd_row, cd_col, columnHeader,bold)
    cd_col += 1
    for ctx in mapping_records:
        spd_record = mapping_records[ctx]
        if spd_record.payment_mode == "CRD":
            cd_row += 1
            cd_col = 0
            cdRow = (spd_record.id, spd_record.erocode, spd_record.scno)
        for columnData in cdRow:
           if cd_col == 5 or cd_col == 19 or cd_col ==20 or cd_col ==21:
             worksheetCd.write_number(cd_row, cd_col, columnData, money)
           else:
             worksheetCd.write(cd_row, cd_col, columnData)
           cd_col += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Did you write this script, would be there fault in this? Please copy paste the exact output.

Comment: Are you getting any error .?? of simply it is not writing tot he excel file.??

Comment: If you are only getting the header row, this suggests that `mapping_records` is empty, so the `for ctx in mapping_records:` block does not get executed

Comment: No, No error is coming. Its just printing the header row. And no other data in the file.

Comment: You never call  `workbook.save()`.

Comment: Yes I know, there is no function like workbook.save() for the workbook class.